# GAE Datastore incremental ID

Tags: java, google-app-engine, increment, auto-increment, google-cloud-datastore

in my project(Java) I need incremental ID for entity stored in Datastore. The most important thing for me is that every next value will be greater than the previous.

I tried using DatastoreService.allocateIds(), but after some incremetal ids, it take id from random place in store, and it violates the order.

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can do count + 1, not great though. Why do you need incremental ids?

Comment: @marcadian , This method I use now and it does not seem good to me.
I need to keep consistency entities. The situation is complicated by the large number of them and so that they may be added more than 10K per second.

Comment: look at the memcached api. its the only possible way you can do this. however its hard to implement right if you want to handle the case when the cache is evicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the builtin ID allocator and use another field for your sequential ID. I tried it myself and it is nearly impossible to allocate IDs the way you want and if you make one mistake then your whole ap is b0rked because the IDs can only be used one time.

So use this method: Two IDs, one generated by the datastore and one custom field that is an Integer or a String that has your own ID.

Comment: As a result, I almost did. Such a system is more complex, but after a day of searching for solutions, I realized that automatically generated ID only correct option.

Comment: Actually, if you need sequencial ids, you don't use automatically generated ids, but a sharding counter, see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters .